# Release phase with container registry on heroku runs container

Tags: django, docker, heroku

I created simple project in Django with docker. According to heroku's documentation about release phase with container registry (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#release-phase) I created a new app with postgres addon. To deploy app with docker I executed following commands:

```
heroku container:push web
heroku container:push release
heroku container:release web release
```

But after last command my terminal is blocked and it looks like release phase actually run a container.

```
Releasing images web,release to teleagh... done
Running release command...
[2019-12-30 21:22:00 +0000] [17] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2019-12-30 21:22:00 +0000] [17] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5519 (17)
[2019-12-30 21:22:00 +0000] [17] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2019-12-30 21:22:00 +0000] [27] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 27
```

My goal is tu run django migrations before release. I would really apreciate any help.

Procfile:

```
release: python manage.py migrate
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PORT=8000
WORKDIR /app
ADD requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
ADD . ./
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
CMD gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT teleagh.wsgi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procfile does not make effect when container deploy is used in heroku. If you want to set release phase command I can suggest two options that I have tested a lot:

**1.** Create dedicated Dockerfile for each phase with extensions matching the phase name.

*Dockerfile.web*

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PORT=8000
WORKDIR /app
ADD requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
ADD . ./
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
CMD gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT teleagh.wsgi
```

*Dockerfile.release*

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PORT=8000
WORKDIR /app
ADD requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
ADD . ./
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
CMD python manage.py migrate
```

The deploying process will be looking the same like yours with one exception — push command must have additional argument *--recursive*. Moreover it is possible to push all containers in one command:

```sh
heroku container:push web release --recursive
heroku container:release web release
```

**2.** Create a bash script to detect what phase is running in the container at the moment.

*start.sh*

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$SSH_CLIENT" ] && [ -n "$HEROKU_EXEC_URL" ];
then
    source <(curl --fail --retry 3 -sSL "$HEROKU_EXEC_URL")
fi

if [[ "$DYNO" =~ ^release.* ]];
then
    set -e
    python3 manage.py migrate
else
    exec gunicorn teleagh.wsgi  -b 0.0.0.0:${PORT} --reload --access-logfile -
fi
```

Then the only *Dockerfile* will be looking like:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PORT=8000
WORKDIR /app
ADD requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
ADD . ./
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
CMD ./start.sh
```

Hope this will be helpful

Comment: This seems to be solution but what is that part of the documentation about? It looks like that Procfile should take effect. Or maybe I don't understand somthing.

Comment: You can read about Procfile here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile . Docker container provides all the environment with an application included. Thats why Procfile does not take effect unlike it happens with git deploy where heroku needs to detect and decide what process types it has to serve for an application pushed in heroku git repository. So heroku can not look inside container and read Procfile, you have to choose another way to create required phases and process types.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a release phase to the `heroku.yml` file.

ex.

```
build:
  ...
release:
  command:
    - rake db:migrate
run:
  web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

[Source](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1390)